# Numpy slice 2D array with every two alternating elements

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an elegant way to slice a `numpy` array such that every second element (alternating by the row) is extracted? (assume the width and height are multiples of 2)

example extraction pattern:

```
[[ X, - , X , -],
 [ -, X , - , X],
 [ X, - , X , -],
 [ -, X , - , X],
 ...]]
```

where `X` means extract this element and `-` don't.

The result will either be half the width or half the height of the original array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that with strides, as there is no way you can address those elements with a simple function.

Fancy indexing using e.g. a mask would be the way to go. This seems fairly elegant:

```
>>> arr = np.random.random_integers(0,9, (4,4))
>>> mask = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: (i+j)%2 ==0 , arr.shape, dtype=int)
>>> np.ma.masked_array(arr, mask=~mask)
masked_array(data =
 [[0 -- 1 --]
 [-- 7 -- 6]
 [9 -- 9 --]
 [-- 1 -- 3]],
             mask =
 [[False  True False  True]
 [ True False  True False]
 [False  True False  True]
 [ True False  True False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

The last line is merely for demonstration purposes. If you want to extract the data, use the indexing: `arr[mask]`, optionally followed by a `reshape(arr.shape[0]//2, -1)` if you need it back in 2 dimensions. This method also works when the array's width and height are not multiples of 2.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a while I also found an answer which will halve the width of the original array

```
x = np.random.random((6,4))

res = np.vstack(zip(x[0::2, 0::2], x[1::2, 1::2])).reshape((x.shape[0], x.shape[1]//2))
```